# Setting background-color for Forio Contour charts

Tags: d3.js, charts, forio-contour

I'm using the Forio Contour charting library - I can't figure out a way to set the background color for my charts (see jsfiddle). It always inherits the bg of the container div which is not what I want.

http://jsfiddle.net/Y4EVP/1/

```
$(function () {
    var data = [22, 8, 5, 19, 11, 4, 5, 13, 20, 29, 25];

    new Contour({
        el: '.chart',
    })
    .cartesian()
    .line(data)
    .render();
});
```

Couldn't find any related properties on http://forio.com/contour/documentation.html - am I missing something?

Comment: `svg { background-color: lightpink;}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

1. You could set the `background-color` to the `svg` using css, which will set the background for the whole chart (including the axis and labels) if that's what you want
2. if you want to add a background color just to the plot area (ie, the axis and labels remain with the container's background), you could create an extension that is just a rect with the size of the plot area and then add that new extension to your chart in the correct order, something like:

   ```
   Contour.export('background', function (color, layer, options) {

     layer.enter().append('rect')
       .attr('class', 'custom-background')
       .attr('x', options.chart.plotLeft)
       .attr('y', options.chart.plotTop)
       .attr('width', options.chart.plotWidth)
       .attr('height', options.chart.plotHeight)
   });
   ```

now you have control of the background color with css:

```
.custom-background {
   fill: #f00;
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Hope this helps